# Twitterkit - Login session will remain even after reinstalling app

Tags: ios, objective-c, session, twitter, twitterkit

Login implement by twitterkit.

Get login status by following code, and login processing is executed if userId can be taken.

`TWTRSession *session = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] sessionStore] session];`

At this time, even if reinstall the App, login information remains and log in.

I tried the following, but I can't log out.

· Reinstall App

· Log out with Twitter App

· Log out Twitter from Safari

· Turn off the third party linkage of the application with the Twitter account

if somebody want to switch accounts,
How should we solve it? Should I implement a logout button?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Do you have any idea how to resolve this ?